# how does c++ separate declaration and constructor-call at the time of object instantiation?

Tags: c++

```
class C {  
public:  
    int i = 0;  
    C() {i++;}  
};

int main()  
{
    C c;  
    // This simple statement could be interpreted something like,            
    // C c;  --> declaration                                                                                                                                                              
    // C::C(&c); -> constructor call                                                                                                                                                      
    return 0;
}
```

My questions Here are,
    1) Does compiler actually do this transformation?
    2) If yes, is there a way to see these transformation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1) Does compiler actually do this transformation?

No.

First, it's not declaration. It's **definition**. Upon definition, a class instance is immediately initialized using one of its constructors.

The compiler does not "transform" a definition into a declaration and a constructor call. It's is exactly what a definition consists of. At preprocessing time, the definition is left as a definition. At compile time, it is compiled into a series of instructions that allocates space for the instance and calls the constructor.

> 2) If yes, is there a way to see these transformation?

No. You can only observe the constructor call in the assembly code, which you likely don't want to look into.

Comment: I kinda like to look at the assembly from time to time. It sometimes gives you ideas where you can tighten up the source code. Not as much as it used to back when we were painting the code on cave walls, but it is still educational.